# error with runit and upstart

Tags: package-management, software-installation, dpkg, upstart, runit

Yesterday i try to install some package and i get error about runit . So i search on Internet and a fix was to

```
sudo dpkg --force runit
```

i did it but as i tried today

```
sudo apt-get update
```

i got this errror

```
E: dpkg was interrupted, you must manually run 'sudo dpkg --configure -a' to correct the problem.
```

But then i tried configuring runit package and here is the error i get

```
start: Unable to connect to Upstart: Failed to connect to socket /com/ubuntu/upstart: Connection refused
dpkg: error processing package runit (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Processing triggers for man-db (2.7.0.2-5) ...
Processing triggers for fontconfig (2.11.1-0ubuntu6) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 runit
```

Please help me how to fix this

Comment: `sudo dpkg --force runit` does absolutely nothing.

Comment: Which version of Ubuntu? Did you install `runit` from the repositories?

Comment: [Edit] your question and add the output of `apt-cache policy runit`

Comment: And what's your goal, install or remove `runit`?

Comment: Not longer interested?

Comment: Seeing that this covers the same ground as http://askubuntu.com/questions/654951/ and http://askubuntu.com/questions/614970/, it's almost certainly version 15, muru.  (-:

Answer (score 2):

The following answer worked for me.  I found it [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/728581/how-to-fix-error-processing-package-git-daemon-run/728748#728748).  I ran into this problem after trying to upgrade `git` with `sudo apt-get install git-all`.

I forcibly remove and then re-install `runit` like so:

```
sudo dpkg -r --force-all runit
sudo apt-get -f install runit
```