# How to fix error processing package git-daemon-run?

Tags: apt, php, git

I am trying to install php curl like so:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install php5-curl
```

But I keep getting an error.

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
php5-curl is already the newest version.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 3 not upgraded.
2 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] Y
Setting up runit (2.1.2-3ubuntu1) ...
start: Unable to connect to Upstart: Failed to connect to socket /com/ubuntu/upstart: Connection refused
dpkg: error processing package runit (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of git-daemon-run:
 git-daemon-run depends on runit; however:
  Package runit is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package git-daemon-run (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
                          Errors were encountered while processing:
 runit
 git-daemon-run
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

when I try **sudo dpkg --configure -a** I get:

```
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of git-daemon-run:
 git-daemon-run depends on runit; however:
  Package runit is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package git-daemon-run (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Errors were encountered while processing:
 git-daemon-run
```

when I try **sudo apt-get install --reinstall runit** I get:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 1 reinstalled, 0 to remove and 8 not upgraded.
2 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
E: Internal Error, No file name for runit:amd64
```

when I try **sudo apt-get install runit** I get:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
runit is already the newest version.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 8 not upgraded.
2 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] Y
Setting up runit (2.1.2-3ubuntu1) ...
start: Job is already running: runsvdir
dpkg: error processing package runit (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of git-daemon-run:
 git-daemon-run depends on runit; however:
  Package runit is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package git-daemon-run (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
                                                                                                          Errors were encountered while processing:
 runit
 git-daemon-run
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

when I try **sudo apt-get install --reinstall git-daemon-run** I get:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 1 reinstalled, 0 to remove and 8 not upgraded.
2 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
E: Internal Error, No file name for git-daemon-run:amd64
```

How can I fix this?

System Specs:

```
Processor: Intel® Core™ i7-3630QM CPU @ 2.40GHz × 8
Graphics: Gallium 0.4 on AMD TURKS (DRM 2.43.0, LLVM 3.6.2)
OS Type: Ubuntu 15.10 64-bit
```

Comment: `sudo dpkg --configure -a`

Comment: @Raphael no it didnt work i am getting **Package runit is not configured yet**

Comment: `sudo apt-get install --reinstall runit`

Comment: @Raphael i tried the reinstall command and now i am getting **E: Internal Error, No file name for runit:amd64**

Comment: Do a `sudo apt-get update`

Comment: @Raphael **update** was successful but i still get **E: Internal Error, No file name for runit:amd64** on **reinstall**

Comment: Then just try `sudo apt-get install runit`

Comment: @Raphael it didn't work I updated my question

Comment: It happens because as said `git`  depends on `runit`. Try `sudo apt-get install --reinstall git-daemon-run`

Comment: @Raphael it didn't work, check the result of the command in the question

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/35168/discussion-between-waqleh-and-raphael).

Comment: I'm not a linux expert. But I removed both git-daemon-run and runit, respectively and things worked (^_^)'!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I forcibly remove `runit` like so:

```
sudo dpkg -r --force-all runit
```

then

```
sudo apt-get -f install runit
```

then installed `php-curl`:

```
sudo apt-get install php5-curl
```

And it was fixed.

Comment: This didn't work for me. I still get the exact same error on running the runit install command!

Answer (score 1):

Install git-daemon-sysvinit first.

```
sudo apt-get install git-daemon-sysvinit
```

Then install php5-curl.

git-daemon-sysvinit replaces git-daemon-run. (They are alternatives for each other.) git-daemon-run doesn't actually work anymore on Ubuntu 15.04 and up, from my experience, and from what I have read. At least, not without special handling. (https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/runit/+bug/1448164)