# While trying to install git, "errors were encountered while processing: runit, git-daemon-run"

Tags: apt, git, runit

I'm trying to install git using

```
sudo apt-get install git-all
```

but I'm getting an error message which ends as follows:

```
Errors were encountered while processing:
 runit
 git-daemon-run
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

I've tried purging runit, git-all, and git, autoremoving, and re-installing as suggested in [How to fix error processing package git-daemon-run?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/728581/how-to-fix-error-processing-package-git-daemon-run), but I still get the same error message. Any ideas on how to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try installing git-daemon-sysvinit first. It replaces git-daemon-run. (They are alternatives for each other.) And unlike git-daemon-run, git-daemon-sysvinit actually works on Ubuntu 15.04 and up. (See https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/runit/+bug/1448164)

Once you have git-daemon-sysvinit installed, you can install git-all, and you shouldn't have any more problems.