# dpkg: error processing package (Ubuntu 16.04)

Tags: dpkg, git

I'm running Ubuntu 16.04. After install git (and later git-all), I'm getting the following errors whenever I try to run "sudo apt-get upgrade".

```
Setting up runit (2.1.2-3ubuntu1) ... start: Unable to connect to
Upstart: Failed to connect to socket /com/ubuntu/upstart: Connection
refused dpkg: error processing package runit (--configure): 
subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit
status 1 No apport report written because the error message indicates
it's a follow-up error from a previous failure.
No apport report written because MaxReports has already been reached
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of git-daemon-run:  git-daemon-run depends on runit; however:   Package
runit is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package git-daemon-run (--configure): 
dependency problems - leaving unconfigured dpkg: error processing
package imagemagick-6.q16 (--configure):  package is in a very bad
inconsistent state; you should  reinstall it before attempting
configuration dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of
imagemagick:  imagemagick depends on imagemagick-6.q16 (=
8:6.8.9.9-7ubuntu5.1); however:   Package imagemagick-6.q16 is not
configured yet.

pkg: error processing package imagemagick (--configure):  dependency
problems - leaving unconfigured Errors were encountered while
processing:  runit  git-daemon-run  imagemagick-6.q16  imagemagick E:
Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Help?

Comment: Try running `sudo apt-get install -f` to fix dependencies.

Comment: I get the same errors when I try that.

Comment: OK, try to reinstall those broken packages `sudo apt-get install --reinstall git-daemon-run imagemagick`

Comment: Still get the same errors :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out that installing git-all breaks Ubuntu 16.04. Found the fix here:

[Failed to connect to socket /com/ubuntu/upstart: Connection refused: Errors were encountered while processing: runit](https://askubuntu.com/questions/654951/failed-to-connect-to-socket-com-ubuntu-upstart-connection-refused-errors-were)

Answer (score 0):

Type in terminal:

```
dpkg --configure -a
apt autoremove
apt -f install
apt update
apt upgrade
```

Comment: All five commands get me the same error (same as described in the question).

Comment: @AssafHershko seems like you accepted my answer, but yet you are saying that you still get the same error?